# Problems getting to work a C multidimensional char array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, char

I would appreciate some guidance about the following code to get it working properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define charLength  5
#define bytesLength charLength*sizeof(char)
int n;
char**  T=0;
void fillT(int n){
    char* __T[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        __T[i] = (char*)malloc(bytesLength);
        scanf("%s",__T[i]);
    }
    T = __T;
}
void foo(){
    n = 3;
    fillT(n);
}
int main(){
    foo();
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){  //works OK
        printf("%d %s\n",i,T[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){  //doesn't work!!!, Why???
        printf("%s\n",T[i]);
    }
}
```

I need to get the last for loop working but, for some reason that I can't understand, I couldn't.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtzCG.png) is the current output.

Comment: What do you think happens to `char*           __T[n];` when `fillT()` returns?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Share the error messages or the expected output vs false output. Also, this seems like a debugging homework.

Comment: I've added a screen capture; the expected output is the first for loop, the wrong putput is two blank lines at the end; In fact, this is a small model of 2K lines project which for some reason Im stuck on. Many thanks for your replies.

Comment: @practicante I won't be notified if you don't tag me in your comments. I don't know what project you are talking about, but I'll try to help you anyways. Let me check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

`char* __T[n];`

Where every other string item is dynamic in your code, this is a loner. This variable (array of strings) is stack allocated. So, it will be dead after the function `fillT` terminates. But you are assigning it to a global variable before quitting the function, then what's the problem? This gives rise to a big problem: **Undefined Behaviour**.

The global `char** T` is pointing to something which is already destroyed. Trying to access it inside both the loops is undefined behaviour. When I ran the code, both the loops gave a wrong output. I wonder how you got the correct output in the first loop, maybe you were just lucky because undefined behaviour can mean anything.

**Solution:**

Make the stack allocated `__T` a heap allocated variable, which will make it live until your program terminates or you `free` it.

Replace `char* __T[n];` with

`char** __T = malloc(n * sizeof(char*));`

Comment: First of all, many thanks for your time and patience to try my code, I'll try your advice.